# Bash command check if string match in command output

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have following command output

```bash
$ /opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --aid | grep 'aid='
aid="fdwe234wfgrgf34tfsf23rwefwef3".
```

I want to check if there is any string after `aid=` (inside ""). If there is any string, command return code should be `0` and if no value return code must be `!=0`.

Can someone please help to extend this command to get required output?

Idea is to make sure my bash script to fail if `aid=` doesn't has any value.

Comment: You could use `grep -q`, which has exactly the exit status behaviour you describe: `falconctl -g aid | grep -q 'aid="[^"]*YOURSTRING[^"]*"'`

Comment: Or are you looking for "not empty", and not a specific string?

Comment: `falconctl ... | grep -q 'aid="..*"'` might be what you want.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. The string after the `aid=` is very dynamic. That's why I want to check if any value present in the aid.

Comment: could you update the question to show an example of what 'no value' looks like ... `aid=""`? `aid=`? something else?

Comment: Hi @M.NejatAydin, could you please clarify what does `"..*"` do in this case?

Comment: @hlesnt395h It matches if there is at least one character enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to check whether one or more characters exist inside the double quotes. And, you can use regex capture group to extract that value:

```bash
if [[ $(/opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --aid | grep 'aid=') =~ ^aid=\"(.+)\"$ ]]; then
  aid=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
  echo "aid is $aid"
else
  echo "aid not found"
fi
```

Note that the regex I use is `.+` which means 1 or more characters, since you require the string to be non-empty. This is in contrast of the usual `.*` regex which would have be 0 or more characters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `falconctl` on my system so to mimic its output I'll use a couple files:

```
$ head falcon*out
==> falcon.1.out <==
some stuff
aid="fdwe234wfgrgf34tfsf23rwefwef3".
some more stuff

==> falcon.2.out <==
some stuff
aid=""
some more stuff
```

One `grep` idea:

```
grep -Eq '^aid="[^"]+"' <filename>
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex support
- `-q` - run in silent/quiet mode (suppress all output)
- the return code can be captured from `$?`

Taking for a test drive:

```
for fname in falcon*out
do
    printf "\n############# %s\n" "$fname"
    cat "$fname" | grep -Eq '^aid="[^"]+"' "$fname"
    echo "return code: $?"
done
```

This generates:

```
############# falcon.1.out
return code: 0

############# falcon.2.out
return code: 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Let me try this out and come back here.